# Dash case (Kebab case) data binding in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In Angular 2, I call a web service and it respond data properly,

but when I'm going to bind that data, It's not binding for Kebab case property(**company-name**).

```
<div *ngFor="let company of companyDetailsList">
     {{company.company-name}}
</div>
```

but it's bind perfect for

```
<div *ngFor="let company of companyDetailsList">
     {{company.address}}
</div>
```

Comment: There are other kebab-case related discussions on the Angular github. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5812

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript dashes are not allowed in variable names. The interpreter will think this is a subtraction.

You can however access the property like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let company of companyDetailsList">
     {{company["company-name"]}}
</div>
```